# jsonfying the select box options

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've a server side query which generically generated all select box options in the form

```
<option val='1'> text1 </option>
<option val='2'> text2 </option>
<option val='3'> text3 </option>
<option val='4'> text4 </option>
<option val='5'> text5 </option>
```

Now I want to convert all of this to a format that jqgrid understands for its dropdowns. i.e. {1:text1, 2:text2....} Condition is that I would not touch the server side code. I need to modify it here at client side by adding a generic function. Now I get this through an jquery ajax call

```
 getGridDropDown: function (url) {
        $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (html) {
         $(html).find('option').each(function(key){
             alert(key)
         })


      },
      error: function () {
        console.log("Error in ajax call to url:  " + url);
      }
    });
 },
```

Now I tried various formats, the only way looks like using regexp is the only way. Can't I handle the html return variable as a jquery variable, where I can say $this.val() + this.text()

Comment: Does your AJAX call return only the `<option>` elements, or are they wrapped in a container?

Comment: @SaiKrishna well, if any of the answers worked tick it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server can generate the list of `<options>` inside of `<select>` you can use directly `dataUrl` in the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) or [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options).

If your server can only generate the list of `<options>` **without** `<select>` and `</select>` and you can't change the behavior on the server side you can use `buildSelect` to fix the problem:

```
editoptions: {
    dataUrl: 'yourUrl',
    buildSelect: function (data) {
        return "<select>" + data + "</select>";
    }
}
```

(in case of usage of old version of jqGrid it could be required to test the `typeof(data)` and use `data` or `data.responseText`)

The usage of `ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }` could be also required (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422265/jqgrid-dataurl-dropdown-list-not-refreshing/7422410#7422410))

Comment: @Sai Krishna: You are welcome! Do you tried this? Is it work in your environment?

Comment: Awesome, I tried. it works better than my fix. my fix is adding undefined as one of the param

Comment: This works great, but I'm somehow trying to add in the same place an input type=hidden element which stores the selected value. I added this to editoptions `dataEvents: [
                               { type: 'change',  fn: function(e) {  console.log(e);
                               html = '<input type=text name=product_codes['+rowObject.invoice_item_id+'] value="'+e.currentTarget.options.value+'" />'; return html;
                               }},
                               
                              ]` , but this does not work. Can you help me in achieving this? Thank You

Comment: @SaiKrishna: the event handler of `change` event should not return HTML fragment. I don't understand what you want to make. Moreover the main purpose of the stackoverflow **to share good question and helpful answers with other people**. New questions from comments will be very bad found. So I suggest you to ask *new question* where you describe carefully your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use find the returned html needs a valid root element.

Try the following:

```
$("<div/>").append(data).find('option')
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zZLV/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj;
$('option').each(function (i,n){
   obj[i] = $(n).text();
});
```

console.log(obj);//outputs your info... on your console

I think this, should do it, but fix the selector so u have `#select_tag_id option`

Answer (score 0):

it was quiet easy. A simple trick did

```
getGridDropDown: function (url) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async:false,
          url: url,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (html) {
             data = new String();
             $(html).each(function(key){
```

/* jqgrid select options format */

```
     data += this.value +":"+this.label+";";
             })
           gridParams['data'] = data     
          },
          error: function () {
            console.log("Error in ajax call to url:  " + url);
          }
        });
     },
```

Thank you for your answers