# How to implement edit inline in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

i starter in jqgrid, i want implement inline edit in jqgrid i have this grid

```js
$(function () {
    var grid = $('#list');
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
        postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceCost', Action: 'Fill' },
        ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
        loadonce: true,
        datatype: 'json',
        height: 490,
        colNames: ['REQUEST_ID','WAYBILL_NO', 'COST_ID', 'COST_NAME','COST_AMOUNT', 'CURRENCY_ID ', 'CURRENCY_NAME','REMARK'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'REQUEST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true,hidden:true },
            { name: 'WAYBILL_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'COST_ID', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'COST_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true },
            { name: 'COST_AMOUNT', width: 100, sortable: true },
            { name: 'CURRENCY_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'CURRENCY_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true },
            { name: 'REMARK', width: 200, sortable: true }
        ],
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 40, 60],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'REQUEST_ID',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'ASC',
        rownumbers: true,
        editurl: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
               lastsel = id;
            }
         }
        });
        grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true }, {}, {}, {},
            { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });
```

i first fill all costType in jqgrid and i Want user Enter amount in Amount Cell and select currency unit in currency_unit cell, in this grid when user click in row , this row change editable, but i want when page is load all row is editable.
thanks all.

i Change Code But i can't get data row for save in Database i write this code

```js
$(function () {
    var lastSel;
    var grid = $('#list');
    calculateTotal = function () {
        var totalAmount = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'COST_AMOUNT', false, 'd');
        var totalTax = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'COST_NAME', false, 'd');
        alert(totalAmount.length);
        for (var i = 0; i <= totalAmount.length - 1; i++) {
            alert(totalTax[i] + "=" + totalAmount[i]);
        }
    };
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
        postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceCost', Action: 'Fill' },
        ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
        loadonce: true,
        direction: "rtl",
        datatype: 'json',
        height: 490,
        colNames: ['REQUEST_ID','WAYBILL_NO', 'COST_ID', 'COST_NAME','COST_AMOUNT', 'CURRENCY_ID ', 'CURRENCY_NAME','REMARK'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'REQUEST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'WAYBILL_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'COST_ID', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'COST_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true },
            { name: 'COST_AMOUNT', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'CURRENCY_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'CURRENCY_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'REMARK', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true }
        ],
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 30,
        rowList: [30, 60, 90],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'REQUEST_ID',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'ASC',
        caption: 'درخواست ها......',
        rownumbers: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            var $this = $(this), rows = this.rows, l = rows.length, i, row;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                row = rows[i];
                if ($.inArray('jqgrow', row.className.split(' ')) >= 0) {
                    $this.jqGrid('editRow', row.id, true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true }, {}, {}, {},
        { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });

    $("#btnsave").click(function () {
        calculateTotal();
    });
});
```

but this code no work, mr oleg thanks for help me.

EDIT02: I Create this

[image]

with this code. i want when user click save button all data all row send to server but not work

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mydata = [
            { COST_NAME: "A", COST_AMOUNT: "", CURRENCY_NAME: "" },
            { COST_NAME: "b", COST_AMOUNT: "", CURRENCY_NAME: "" },
            { COST_NAME: "c", COST_AMOUNT: "", CURRENCY_NAME: "" },
            { COST_NAME: "d", COST_AMOUNT: "", CURRENCY_NAME: "" },
            { COST_NAME: "e", COST_AMOUNT: "", CURRENCY_NAME: "" },
            { COST_NAME: "f", COST_AMOUNT: "", CURRENCY_NAME: "" },
            { COST_NAME: "g", COST_AMOUNT: "", CURRENCY_NAME: "" }
        ];
    var lastSel;
    var grid = $('#list');
    calculateTotal = function () {
        var totalAmount = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'COST_AMOUNT', false, 'd');
        var totalTax = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'COST_NAME', false, 'd');
        alert(totalAmount.length);
        for (var i = 0; i <= totalAmount.length - 1; i++) {
            alert(totalTax[i] + "=" + totalAmount[i]);
        }
    };
    grid.jqGrid({
        postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceCost', Action: 'Fill' },
        ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
        loadonce: true,
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        mtype: 'POST', 
        height: 'auto',
        colNames: [ 'COST_NAME', 'COST_AMOUNT', 'CURRENCY_NAME'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'COST_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true },
            { name: 'COST_AMOUNT', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'CURRENCY_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true }
        ],
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 30,
        rowList: [30, 60, 90],
        pager: '#pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'ASC',
        rownumbers: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            var $this = $(this), rows = this.rows, l = rows.length, i, row;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                row = rows[i];
                if ($.inArray('jqgrow', row.className.split(' ')) >= 0) {
                    $this.jqGrid('editRow', row.id, true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true }, {}, {}, {},
        { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });

    $("#btnsave").click(function () {
        calculateTotal();
    });
});
```

and body

```html
<table id="list"></table>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="btnsave"/>
```

thanks all

NEW EDIT: i for this problem write this code

```js
grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
    postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceCost', Action: 'Fill' },
    ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
    loadonce: true,
    direction: "rtl",
    pgtext: "صفحه {0} از {1}",
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 490,
    colNames: ['شماره درخواست', 'شماره بارنامه', 'شماره هزینه', 'نام هزینه', 'مبلغ', 'کد واحدهزینه ', 'توضیحات'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'REQUEST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'WAYBILL_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'COST_ID', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'COST_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true },
        { name: 'COST_AMOUNT', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
        { name: 'CURRENCY_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=CurrencyUnit&Action=FillDrop",
                dataInit: function (data) {
                    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                    var s = '<select>';
                    s += '<option value="0">انتخاب کنید</option>';
                    if (response && response.length) {
                        for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
                            var ri = response[i];
                            s += '<option value="' + ri.CURRENCY_ID + '">' + ri.CURRENCY_NAME + '</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    return s + "</select>";

                }
            }
        },
        { name: 'REMARK', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true }
    ],
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [30, 60, 90],
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'REQUEST_ID',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'ASC',
    caption: 'درخواست ها......',
    rownumbers: true,
    loadComplete: function () {
        var strOption = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'JQGridHandler.ashx',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { ActionPage: 'CurrencyUnit', Action: 'FillDrop' },
            success: function (data) {
                var rows = data.rows;
                strOption = '<option value=0>انتخاب کنید</option>';
                if (data.rows.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
                        var ri = rows[i];
                        strOption += '<option value="' + ri.cell[0] + '">' + ri.cell[1] + '</option>';
                    }
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        var $this = $(this);
        rows = this.rows;
        var l = rows.length, i, row;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            row = rows[i];

//              var $t = grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'CURRENCY_ID');
//              var $id = $($t).attr("id");

//              $("#" + $id).val(strOption);
                    // console.log(row.id);

            var selRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', row.id);
               console.log(selRowId);
               console.log(grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'CURRENCY_ID'));

            if ($.inArray('jqgrow', row.className.split(' ')) >= 0) {
                $this.jqGrid('editRow', row.id, true);
            }

        }
    },
    editurl: "jQGridHandler.ashx"
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true }, {}, {}, {},
    { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });
```

first question: this code is true? and i now i can't fill dropdownlist . please help me mr.Oleg. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate all rows in the grid and call `editRow` inside of `loadComplete` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172234/315935) for the code example). You should understand some disadvantages of the approach:

- setting a line of grid in inline editing mode in the loop can work slowly in case of large number of rows. So you should carefully choose `rowNum` in the case. The reason of the slow performance is simple: every change of one element on the page follow to *recalculation of positions of all other elements on the page* or at least to [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow). `editRow` method change one cell in the row, then change another one and so on. Applying of `editRow` in the loop for all rows follows to reflow of the whole page after every cell modifications. In case of large grid you will have a lot of reflows.
- If you will need to read information from editing rows you will need to do some tricks because `getRowData` and `getCol` will not work in the case. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129908/315935) you can find the corresponding solution. If if would be enough for you to get last saved data you can use `getLocalRow` method.

**UPDATED**: The keyboard navigation between editable rows is in reality absolutely another question. Nevertheless you can bind `keydown`event on the grid for example and change focus on the another cell if it's needed. For example [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/InlineEditWithKeyboardNavigation.htm) shows for how <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys can be used together with the standard <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> keys:

```js
$('#list').keydown(function (e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"),
        $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow"),
        ci, ri, rows = this.rows;
    if ($td.length === 0 || $tr.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    ci = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
    ri = $tr[0].rowIndex;
    if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.UP) { // 38
        if (ri > 0) {
            $(rows[ri-1].cells[ci]).find("input,select").focus();
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.DOWN) { // 40
        if (ri + 1 < rows.length) {
            $(rows[ri+1].cells[ci]).find("input,select").focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @ oleg: very thanks, but if i want when user prese down arrow key in keyboad focus go to next row, please help me. thanks.

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: I modified my answer to include additional keyboard navigation. You last question with modified code I can't understand. You use `editurl: 'jQGridHandler.ashx'` so the data will be *automatically* send to the server on saving. So you can call `saveRow` in the same loop as you call `editRow`. Every such call will send the current data from the row to the server. Your current code which use `calculateTotal` is unclear for me.

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: Sorry, but I explained you before that you have to call `saveRow` for all rows of the grid inside of `$("#btnsave").click(...)` to send the modified data to the server. Instead of that you call `calculateTotal` which do nothing important. Moreover the function `calculateTotal` use `getCol` which can't be used in editing mode (see my answer). Either you have to get data from `<input>` elements of jqGrid manually (like I described in **UPDATED** part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129908/315935)) or you have to stop editing by calling of `saveRow`.

Comment: Mr Oleg I edit Question, please help me. this problem is very important. thanks.

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: You code have some problems. You use `url` and `dataInit` properties of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) instead of usage `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4102155/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7836314/315935)). Moreover I don't understand what do `$.ajax` inside of `loadComplete`. I suppose that it's your some old code which are not used now.

Comment: @ Oleg: please check this page and help me. thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242987/how-to-implement-inline-editining-in-jqgrid